# Retrieve SUM of few selected rows of a column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I was trying to get a sum of few selected rows of Money Column in a database.

The sql is below.

```
$sql_total_money = "SELECT SUM(Money) as TotalMoney FROM accounts WHERE Program='PSC' BranchId='13' and ExamYear='2013'";
$result_total_money=mysql_query($sql_total_money,$link)or die($sql_total_money."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$row_total_money=mysql_fetch_array($result_total_money);
```

This is giving an error like below because of die function.

```
SELECT SUM(Money) as TotalMoney FROM accounts WHERE Program='PSC' BranchId='10' and ExamYear='2013'

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BranchId='10' and ExamYear='2013'' at line 1
```

What can i do and what is the solution?

Comment: Please, please, please stop using `mysql_*`.

Comment: use PDO or mysqli instead for security and other reasons. check [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php‎) and [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php‎)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed an `AND` after `Program='PSC'`:

```
SELECT SUM(Money) as TotalMoney
FROM   accounts
WHERE  Program='PSC'
       AND BranchId='10'
       AND ExamYear='2013'
```

Comment: thanks... @mishik i didn't see that and i got stuck for an hour for that...thanks anyway...

Comment: @user2557992 - for saying thank and supporting you can accept the answer.

Comment: @user2557992 You should accept the answer if this worked for you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to club your condition(s) using conditional operator `AND/OR` like

```
SELECT SUM(Money) as TotalMoney 
FROM accounts 
HAVING Program='PSC' and
BranchId='10' and 
ExamYear='2013'
```